# Can't find/display info in browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest, visual-studio-2012

New to VS 2012 MVC applications, first time doing RESTful API (currently [at this point in the tutorial)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api#Exercise3) and I can't seem to get info to properly display in Google Chrome. Having set breakpoints as shown in the tutorial in my Controller's Get() function, I know it is being called, and when checking the Network View in the browser, [it sees both of my entries I'm trying to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRjLY.png).

My code is practically identical to the example, with titles switched out:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="body">
    <ul id="drug_entries"></ul>
</div>

@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $.getJSON('/api/DrugEntry', function (drugEntriesJsonPayload)
        {
            $(drugEntriesJsonPayload).each(function (i, item)
            {
                $('#drug_entries').append('<li>' > + item.NDC + '</li>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Any idea what might be the cause of it not seeing anything? Or if there's more information I can provide? Thanks!

My route.config:

```
// <auto-generated/>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MedicationsShortagesDashboard
{
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

My WebApiConfig.cs:

```
// <auto-generated/>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MedicationsShortagesDashboard
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
            // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
            // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
            //config.EnableQuerySupport();

            // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
            // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, you can provide us with your route.config, or have you not configured it there?

Comment: I have not, here it is, possibly missed a step? http://pastebin.com/SQ56A1BC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace XXX
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Convention-based routing.
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's saying that the route "DefaultApi" is already in the Route Collection, but I have no idea where that is. Also, what are my web api signatures? I'm seriously newb at this.

Comment: Ah, that exact bit of code is already in WebApiConfig.cs, was that what you thought was missing?

Comment: Look carefully at the route template, it starts with /api instead of controller

Comment: I'm confused, should I remove this from WebApiConfig.cs and put it in RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: edited the answer, my mistake on confusing the WebApiConfig.cs & RouteConfig.cs

Comment: if it still doesn't work, please post your webapi code snippet

Comment: It didn't do anything, only prevented the page from seeing the data in /api/DrugEntry at all. Editing my main post now.

Comment: you should be able to see some output from /api/drugentry from the browser if configured properly